# Disable input when enter is pressed dynamically

Tags: angular

I'm making a website where there will be a lot of input fields. Sort of like a scanner, I would like to disable each input when the enter is pressed.

I now have this:

`<input (keyup.enter)="doSomething()"/>`

But I would want to pass along the input itself so I can disable these inputs. (f.e. something like: `doSomething(input) { input.attr.disabled = true; }`

How can I get this input field in my `doSomething` function?

**Note**: I do not want to use something like `<input #input ...` since I have so many input fields. This will only create a lot of work.

All I want is that each time the enter is pressed in an input field, that it gets disabled (using only one function for all).

Comment: Did you try using target event property?

Comment: No, can you give an example of how I can pass the event to my function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a directive that listens for the `keyup.enter` on the input and then sets the disabled attribute on the input. This can be done with a directive like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[disable-on-enter]',
})
export class DisableOnEnterDirective {
  @HostBinding('attr.disabled') isDisabled;
  @HostListener('keyup.enter') disableInput() {
   this.isDisabled = true ;
  }
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```html
<input disable-on-enter placeholder="Press enter to disable" />
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhFHsRjoiRX1eAHTWbyf?p=preview)

Comment: awesome answer, love the directive idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
<input (keyup.enter)="doSomething($event)"/>

doSomething(event) {  event.target.disabled = true; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try something like this,

```
<input id="reply" name="reply" onKeyPress="enterpressalert(event)"/>

<script>
function enterpressalert(e){
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
 e.target.disabled = true;
}
}
</script>
```